# Google Coral.ai Developer Board - basic terminal issue under windows 10 - "your terminal lacks the ability to clear the screen

Tags: google-coral, pycoral

When i try to complete the initial setup process on my I sun into a problem.

using this guide: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started

I get step 4 "Connect to the board's shell via MDT"

I can complete with success the following commands:

"mdt devices" (I get a Hostname and IP Add)- Success

"mdt shell" (I see the boards shell prompt) - Success

on Step 5 it all goes south:

I type in "nmtui" and immediately I am met with this error message: "your terminal lacks the ability to clear the screen or position of the cursor"

I tried using Windows powershell (as an Administrator) and the result is the same.

I tried Google but I can only find the problem with people using Linux....

I tried installing Putty till I read this from the guide:

"Note: You must connect to the board via MDT over USB at least once before you can SSH via any other method. Using USB allows MDT to generate an SSH public/private key pair and push it to the board's authorized_keys file, which then allows you to authenticate with SSH. (Using MDT is just easier than manually copying the key over the serial console."

Any idea on how to address this would be great